# displaying array difference in php when arrays coming from mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, array-difference

I'm designing a php script which shows the available buses of a certain travel agency on a given date. This is the php code snippet.

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT bus_id FROM schedule WHERE travel_agency_id = '".$travel_agency_id."' AND scheduleddate ='".$busDate."'");
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT bus_id FROM pc WHERE travel_agency_id = '".$travel_agency_id."' ");

$array1 = array(@mysql_fetch_array($query1));
$array2 = array(@mysql_fetch_array($query2));
$diff = array_diff($array2, $array1);
print_r ($diff);
```

I thought that the above query will print the `"bus_id"`s of the travel agency id `"$travel_agency_id"` on the given date `"$busDate"`. However an error occurred as following.

> Notice: Array to string conversion in.......... Array ( [0] => )

Could anyone explain why this error occurred..? How can I use `"echo"` to display the array of available buses (id) ?

Comment: Which line of code do you get the notice on? Also what is the entire error?

Comment: the line where the statement  $diff = array_diff($array2, $array1); is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
    $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT bus_id FROM schedule WHERE travel_agency_id = '".$travel_agency_id."' AND scheduleddate ='".$busDate."'");
    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT bus_id FROM pc WHERE travel_agency_id = '".$travel_agency_id."' ");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query1) > 0 && mysql_num_rows($query2) > 0 ){
    $array1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1);
    $array2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
    $diff = array_diff($array2, $array1);
    print_r ($diff);
}
```

Comment: Still error occurs but it is a different error. I learned something that the array what is I expected is not an array..! as this error says... Warning: array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array on line 23

Comment: It seems to be O.K... but not listing anything. Wait I'll inform u. Thanks Boss..!